# Mousedown event for mobile without jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, touch

### Is there a simple *mousedown/mouseup* event that I can use with an Angular-based mobile app?

I'm already using ngTouch for some swiping, but it does not seem to support a 'while-pressed' type of event.

ngMousedown does not work on touch screens, and I would like to avoid jquery if possible. I would like something that I could just stick into a directive and apply to a bunch of different elements.

Comment: Most the events you are using in jQuery are actually events in javascript. [Javscript Event Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events) you can find `mousedown` on this list.

Answer (score 1):

I just ended up using jquery. Here is a directive that applies class while an item is being pressed on a touch screen device. Essentially an `ngmousedown` that works on touch screens.

```
angular.module('app.directives').directive('touchable', function() {
    return {
    restrict: 'A',
    transclude: false,
    scope: false,
    link: function(scope, element, attrs){
        element.on('touchstart', function(){
            $(this).addClass('pressed');
        }).on('touchend', function(){
            $(this).removeClass('pressed');
        });
    }}
});
```